# telnet connection refused despite ufw having ports open

Tags: ubuntu, telnet, ufw

How is this possible?  I dont understand

```
Server A ip=111.111.111.111
Server B ip=222.222.222.222

Server A:
ufw status 
23                         ALLOW       222.222.222.222
9160                       ALLOW       222.222.222.222
Anywhere                   ALLOW       222.222.222.222

Server A
telnet 127.0.0.1 9160
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.


On Server B
telnet 1111.111.111.111 9160
Trying 111.111.111.111...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

How is this possible?  I me]an I have the port open for server B.  This makes no sense....
Yes..a process is running on server A which is cassandra on 9160 demonstrated above with the telnet into 127.0.0.1

How can server B get a connection refused?

FYI...I have cassadra.yaml set the the public facing ip address.

Also on the cassandra server....its listing in 9160

```
lsof -i :9160
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    16593 cassandra   96u  IPv4 66540142      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:9160 (LISTEN)

netstat -apn|grep -w 9160
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9160          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16593/java
```

Comment: Is the process listening on all IP addresses or only on loopback?

Comment: Please show the output of netstat -tnlp | grep :9160

Comment: Ok so now you have a definitive answer to your question - it is as edvinas.me, jennyd and I said - your application is not listening on the external IP address. It should be easy to fix now.

Comment: Given that I have listen_address in cassandra.yaml set to the ip address of the machine...what else do I need to do?

Comment: The answer already given was correct, according to the information you just posted here. Something is clearly wrong with your chef template and you need to go fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Port is open, but Cassandra might be bound to 127.0.0.1 ip only. You have to make sure it is configured to be accessed via non 127.0.0.1 IP.

You need to set `ListenAddress` in cassandra.

Comment: One of many options, yes. OP should try telnet 111.111.111.111 9160 from A. Also, sudo netstat -ntpl on A.

Comment: In cassandra I have the listen address set to the public facing ip address

Comment: So do a `netstat -apn|grep -w 9160` and post the results **in your question**.

Comment: I posted the netstat command

Comment: I stand correct, it is listening on 127.0.0.1 instead of public IP. Please set ListenAddress in cassandra.

Comment: its already set via chef template listen_address: <%=node[:ipaddress] %>

Comment: @Tampa: it is clearly and demonstrably not working.

Answer (score 4):

`Connection Refused` generally means that nothing is listening on the relevant port. Use [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) to confirm where the application is listening and take appropriate action.